# how to automatically detect a value for my user even if user not logged in

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, linux

I am developing a stock market game.  So for this purpose I am fetching data from stock market using an API.

In this game user can sell his/her share at the current price of that share in stock market 
or at any other specific price(decided by user).

**So for example:**

The Current Price for Google Share is $50.

The user wants to sell his 20 shares when the price reaches to $55.

So he fills a form on my website and set 20 shares to sell at the price of $55 and just log 
out from his account.

Suppose after 20 min the market price of Google share reaches to $55 so now the 20 share should be sell automatically.

**SO now My Question is that:**

How can I automatically detect at a periodic interval that share's prices reaches to $55 or not and if yes then the 20 shares should be sell automatically.

I am using PHP,Js,Mysql,AJAX and linux server.

Comment: i know this can be done using Cron job but i am just looking for the other way.

Comment: Well you would need push alerst from your api provider. Generally these would cost money so if you want to keep it free, then one alternative is to make a psuedo cron - basically whenever someone visits the website, it sets off a script asynchronously calls the update page, which will perform the update without any visible slow down to the user. For example slap an ajax call on the page to open up a page called "cron". In the cron page you'd just check the last time that page was called (save that to a file) and then run it if required. This will only work if you have constant visitors

Answer (score 1):

the only other way would be to have the same script you would have used for cron job, run on every page load...and then it would be run whenever any user goes to a page.  This of course is not ideal because if there is a lot of traffic, it gets needlessly triggered over and over...but no traffic would mean no triggering.  Or maybe one person goes to a page every hour..script won't run for an hour.

I suppose another way would be to have your own dedicated browser open and a make a page to request the script and refresh every X seconds, via meta tag or js or whatever.

But anyways, why not use a cron job? That's what it's there for.

Comment: i know the cron is their but i am just asking for the another way but i know cron is one the best ways anyways thanks